# WPTK Pushpin template based on map zoom level

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8, maps, datatemplate, pushpin

In my Windows phone app, Im using windows phone 8 toolkit to place some push pins over the map control.

My map control and push pin looks this:

```
    <maps:Map x:Name="lineMap" ZoomLevel="10">
        <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
                <maptk:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapItemControl">
                    <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <maptk:Pushpin GeoCoordinate="{Binding location}" Template="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplate}" PositionOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </maptk:MapItemsControl>
        </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
    </maps:Map>
```

But how do I change the push pin template based on zoom level? Is it possible to use DataTemplate and how to get the zoom level? Or what is the best way to implement this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

BEst way is to hook into the `ZoomLevelChanged` event of the map control´( details found on [MSDN here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.zoomlevelchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) )

So when this event fires, you can change the style of your `Pushpin` by setting it's `Style` property to one you have defined somewhere...

```
(Pushpin)somePin.Style = Application.Current.Resources["PushpinStyle"] as Style;
```

Comment: All I have in my "code behind" regarding push pins is where I set mapItemControl item source to list of objects. So I do not have push pins defined in my c# code. Can I somehow set the whole mapItemControl style?

Comment: Hmm I see... not sure on how to do that ( I think you'll need to go through the VisualTree ). But take a look here [http://tizianocacioppolini.blogspot.be/2013/06/windows-phone-8-map-and-clusters.html](http://tizianocacioppolini.blogspot.be/2013/06/windows-phone-8-map-and-clusters.html) it does something similar with zoom levels and pushpin templates!